# Eventhub custom endpoint showing NOT Found

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have added eventhub custom endpoints using ARM template and powershell. But for both the methods, the custom endpoint shows NOT Found when I try to click on the endpoint after creation.

The status shows healthy but upon clicking on that, it gives NOT found though the eventhub namespace and eventhub are active and accessible.

```
#read the keys/connectionstring of eventhub
$hubConnectionString1=(az eventhubs eventhub authorization-rule keys list --resource-group $resourceGroup --namespace-name $ehnamespace1 --eventhub-name $ehubname1 --name $SASname1 --query "primaryConnectionString")

# Create Custom endpoints  Eventhub
az iot hub routing-endpoint create --resource-group $resourceGroup --hub-name $iotHubName --endpoint-name $endpointName1 --endpoint-type eventhub --endpoint-resource-group $resourceGroup --connection-string $hubConnectionString1  --endpoint-subscription-id $subscriptionID
```

Comment: have you tried to create the endpoint through the Azure Portal? Does it give the same error?

Comment: it works fine. I'm having issue only with the script/ARM template.

Comment: I tried to add an endpoint using your commands above and it worked for me. Can you check the output of the second command? It should return the list of configured endpoints for the IoT Hub - and should now include your added event hub

Comment: The commands works fine for me too.If I include 6 eventhub custom endpoints then it creates, but when i click on the created custom endpoint, it shows not found though the status shows healthy. Its weird but i have to fix this issue as we are deploying the IOT via azure devops pipeline. I cant keep checking the output  everytime as it will be given to devops to run the pipeline. Any help is much appreciated.